# Writing RCFile - how many reducers?

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have a MapReduce implementation for processing certain logfiles directly into GZip Compressed RCFile, for easy loading into Hive (via external table projections).

In any event, I have code that successfully and correctly runs, emitting data as `BytesRefArrayWritable` into `RCFileOutputFormat`.

Currently, I am running this as a Map-only job, meaning that for N input splits, I get N output files.  For example, for 50 input splits, I will get 50 files of `.rc` extension.  Hive can interpret these files together without issue, but my question is as follows:

**Is it optimal** to have 50 (or N, as it were) `RCFile` in a single directory, or is it optimal to have a single `RCFile` containing all the data?  I know that `RCFile` is a columnar format, so IO is optimized for queries such as filtering on a particular column's value.

In the example I mentioned above with 50 input splits, in the first case, MapReduce will need to open 50 files and seek to the location of a column in question.  It will also be able to parallelize this operation, given that these 50 files will be spread across HDFS.  In the second case (all data in one `RCFile`), I would imagine MapReduce would sequentially stream the column values in the single RCFile and not have to stitch together 50 different results...

Is there a good way to reason about this?  Is it a function of HDFS blocksize and the aggregate size of the Hive table?

Please let me know if I can clarify anything -- thanks in advance

Comment: As a side note, I would urge you to switch to [ORC](https://cwiki.apache.org/Hive/languagemanual-orc.html) files (Hive 0.11). See http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GV7vpR7vpjM

Comment: Yes I plan to switch to ORC or Parquet but stuck with RCFile for now.  I imagine the question still applies to those formats as well.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it a function of HDFS blocksize

Primarily yes. Adjust the number of reducers as to not create partitions smaller than a block.  I would consider this as the main driving factor.

Other than that, a smaller number of files is healthier for the name node. You also get some administrative goodness from *not* having x50 times more partitions than you really need on a Hive table (think operations like removal of obsolete partitions).

And I must reiterate the point of trying to move to the arguably superior [ORC](https://cwiki.apache.org/Hive/languagemanual-orc.html) format.

Comment: Let's assume that each Hive partition has ~100s of GB and each RC file far exceeds HDFS block size -- in this scenario does it matter whether there are 50 RC files or 1 from a performance standpoint, NN memory excepted?

Comment: To clarify -- each partition has the 50 RC files, it's a daily partition

Comment: In this case I wouldn't worry. Of course the best recourse is, as always, to try it out and measure A/B.